# Change default button style

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-theme

I want to define a default style for my buttons so that I don't have to type `style="@style/mainButtonStyle"` inside of each button manually. I have already defined the style.

```
    <style name="mainButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_default_background</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>
```

And already added an `android:buttonStyle` attribute in the app's theme.

**themes.xml**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.PlanShopping" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">#AA0000</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSurface">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/mainButtonStyle</item>
    </style>
```

The Android Manifest has `android:theme` attribute set up by default.

```
    <application
        android:name=".PlannerApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PlanShopping"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        ...
    </application>
```

So why is it not changing the default button style? The style works fine if I type it manually inside of a button. But it's not the result I wanted. How can I set it by default? I've tried to inherit from different types of buttons: `android:Widget.Button`, `android:Widget.Holo.Button`. Also, different `<Button>` types did not help. For now, I'm using a default `<Button>` component (not material or holo).

Comment: Try adding `buttonStyle` without the `android:` prefix

Comment: @Zain unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: Probably you have a night version of styles file; and the app runs on the other version?

Comment: I've tried your guess and set the style for both default and night themes. For some reason, it still has no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the button is a [MaterialButton](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) you will need to specify:

```
<item name="materialButtonStyle">@style/mainButtonStyle</item>
```